# what is the best way to do cryptography in python?

Tags: python, cryptography

im new to python and a few years ago i made a word encryption system on paper and i want to use code to automatically turn plain text into the encrypted version and then be able to decrypt it. what is the way i should plan this out? ive never really done that much with python 3.7 and id really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks! i use a four letter shift to start so A=E etc. and then each letter is given a random two digit number and i also have a few simple words given two digit numbers as well to make it more simple. then after the message is a bunch of numbers i have nine letters that each have a value 0-9 so then you'd turn the numbers into the letters each number represents and you end up with just 10 letters that can be turned into any message. this was just me messing around so i didn't bother with punctuation and things like that. its just a starter project.

P.S. sorry about being a complete noob i just dont have any idea where to start

Comment: The first part you mentioned sounds like a caesar's cipher. [This tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography_with_python/cryptography_with_python_caesar_cipher.htm) is a good starting point for that, and maybe you can go from there!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please see [ask] - your question is currently very open ended and not a great fit for SO.  The first comment provided a good start.  Here's another link you might find helpful: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/crypto/#id1 When you have gotten your hands wet and runs into issue in your projects, please do come back and ask again :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing cryptography-related software in Python requires using a cryptography module. These modules contain implementations of the most popular cryptography algorithms such as encryption / decryption with AES, hashing with SHA, pseudorandom number generators, and much, much more, either in pure python, or as a wrapper around popular cryptographic libraries. Furthermore, since Python supports bignums out of the box, it is an excellent platform for experimenting with cryptographic algorithms.

However, before embarking on this journey, total beginners are strongly encouraged to take a serious "Cryptography 101" course. This is essential to get an overview of the field, and to avoid all too popular beginners mistakes. After all, unlike programming, faulty cryptographic applications don't generate compiler error messages, yet they are still broken. To illustrate: the example that is mentioned in the question is a Ceasar's Cipher, a classic algorithm that gets mentioned in the very first lecture of almost all introductions to cryptography, only to show that it can be easily defeated by a frequency analysis. Another example is that naively composing building blocks / algorithms doesn't necessarily result in secure constructions, even if the algorithms themselves are: e.g. what is secure: [sign-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-sign](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign)?

There are many Cryptography 101 courses on the net, both in textbook, tutorials, and online lecture form. Which one you select is a matter of personal taste. One popular entry point is [Prof. Paar's series of 24 lectures on Basic Applied Cryptography](https://wiki.crypto.rub.de/Buch/en/movies.php) (for total beginners), which is also available on YouTube, but feel free to explore other introductions. If you prefer to learn from books, and since you want to use Python, [Practical Cryptography for Developers](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/) by Svetlin Nakov is a free book-in-progress that may be useful.

No matter what Cryptography 101 course you take, just follow along by doing the exercises and examples in Python, using a crypto module. Of course, implementing such simple algorithms as Ceasar's Cipher doesn't require such a module: this can be done with Python itself and no external module. But as soon as you dive deeper in applied cryptography, crypto modules will become very handy, since implementing current cryptographic algorithms "by hand" can be rather complicated for beginners and experienced users alike, and moreover, it is best practice to use battle-tested and peer-reviewed cryptographic libraries and modules, instead of rolling your own implementations, no matter how instructive that would be.

The takeaway from this answer is that it doesn't matter all that much, which specific tools and languages you use to implement cryptography: you need to get acquainted with the crypto basics first, learn about best practices, don't try to get fancy and don't roll your own solutions. Always keep in mind that errors in the design and use of cryptographic constructions can be subtle, even to experts. Stick to well-used design patterns that have been vetted by the cryptography community. Once you understand the basics, transferring your knowledge to specific programming languages and tools will be almost automatic.

Comment: The last release, pycrypto 2.6.1 is seven years old and widely considered to be **insecure** ... so in what sense is `pycrypto` the **canonical** library?

Comment: You're right! Answer edited to reflect that pycrypto is marked insecure. Should I recommend the "cryptography" module, or is it best to keep the answer generic? Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Cryptography is possibly one of those domains where, unless you are **actually an expert**, a recommendation may be unwise (as it was in this case!)

Comment: Agreed! The "cryptography" module (from cryptography.io) is actively maintained, but that too shouldn't be interpreted as an endorsement regarding quality. That's why I hesitated to add it to the answer. Thanks for the useful feedback.